# Controllador de Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

¿Quisiera saber si es correcto utilizar `AsQueryable` llamando al `dbcontext` de esta manera o si es más producente pasar la lista a una `List` o `IEnumerable` y utilizar su método `IQueryable` para así verificar si existe para guardarlo y después buscarlo o si hay algo más que no allá notado?

````
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(DtoArchivo Entyti)
{
if (_MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Get().AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IdA == Entyti.IdA) != null)
             return new NotFoundObjectResult("El archivo ya esta registrado");

     try
     {
        _MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Insertar(new Archivo()
        {
           IdA = Entyti.IdA,
           InA = DateTime.Now,
           FnA = null,
           EstA = Entyti.EstA
         });
         await _MyEspacio.GuardarTodo();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return new NotFoundObjectResult("No se pudo guardar el registro");
         throw;
      }

var Item = _MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Get().AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IdA == Entyti.IdA).FirstOrDefault();
return new CreatedResult($"https://localhost:7185/api/Archivo/Get/Archivo/{Item.IdA}", Item);
} ```
````

Comment: Cuál es el tipo de dato que te retorna esta función: _MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Get()

Comment: No si es buena forma de medir el lapso de tiempo, pero lo que hice fue colocar un objeto de tipo 'Stopwatch' para que me proyectara en consola el lapso de milisegundos 

Dandome como resultado un total de 819mls

Comment: Rosario Mi pregunta era el TIPO de dato, es un List<DtoArchivo> o un DbSet<DtoArchivo>, o un IEnumerable<DtoArchivo> o otro?

Comment: Es un objeto DbSet<T>

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso no veo sentido a ocupar AsQueryable, no veo que te aporte algo. No obstante tu código se podría mejorar (en mi opinión personal) de esta manera:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(DtoArchivo Entyti)
{
if (_MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Get().Any(x => x.IdA == Entyti.IdA))
             return new NotFoundObjectResult("El archivo ya esta registrado");

     try
     {
         var archivo = new Archivo()
        {
           IdA = Entyti.IdA,
           InA = DateTime.Now,
           FnA = null,
           EstA = Entyti.EstA
         };
        _MyEspacio.DepartamentoArchi.Insertar(archivo);
         await _MyEspacio.GuardarTodo();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return new NotFoundObjectResult("No se pudo guardar el registro");
         throw;
      }

return new CreatedResult($"https://localhost:7185/api/Archivo/Get/Archivo/{Item.IdA}", Archivo);
}
```

1. Where(x => x.IdA == Entyti.IdA) Recorre toda la colección (la tabla) para buscar todos los items que cumplan la condición. En cambio Any(x => x.IdA == Entyti.IdA) recorre la colección hasta que encuentra el primer item que cumple la condición y entrega verdadero o falso según haya encontrado o no
2. Tu creas un Objeto del tipo Archivo y lo guardas. Luego lo vas a buscar para  pasarlo a la función CreatedResult. Yo no lo veo necesario, si lo tienes ahí mismo, para que ir a buscarlo a la base de datos? (a menos que al guardarlo estés ingresándole más datos).

También ocupar DtoArchivo y Archivo yo lo veo algo redundante, no sé en este caso, pero me he encontrado con código que ocupan 2 clases una DTO y la otra "normal" que son iguales, eso no tiene sentido.

Comment: Garcías , lo que pasa de que utilizó 2 datos es que ya hice la base de datos desde el código dando como resultado que el objeto que representa en la base de datos tiene todos los tipos de objetos y sub objetos que tiene más etiquetas y solo necesito especificar algunos datos y no todos

Comment: Cambiaré la DbSet por IQueryable y sobre el dato que devuelve mediante la CreatedResult es que es el mismo dato que recibe, ya que lo que recibe como key es un string , Gracias utlizare la Anu metodo